# How to solve the following equation depending on $a$,$b$,$c$?

Tags: systems-of-equations, symmetric-polynomials

I need to find real numbers $a$,$b$,$c$ so $a+b+c-abc-2=0$. I know that it is true when $a=b=c=1$ but how do I know it does not have or have other solutions? 
Btw I have not found a tag for this question other that that.

Comment: How about $a=b=0$ and $c=2$?  You need to specify what $a,b,c$ are: reals, integers, positive integers?

Comment: Yeah I know there are other solutions but I was thinking if there is an infinity of solutions or not.

Comment: One set of solutions is $(a,a,\frac{2}{a+1})$

Comment: Go to http://www.wolframalpha.com (Wolfram Alpha) and enter the command  

     plot x+y+z-x*y*z=2

You'll see the plot with a lot of points on it.

Comment: $(1,1,c)$ is a solution for any $c$.  In general one should not expect a single equation in *three* variables to have finitely many real solutions (it's possible, but very atypical).

Answer (score 1):

There are many solutions. Take an example, Let $a=0$

The given equation becomes $b+c-2=0$ or $b+c=2$

Since negative and positive numbers are possible, there are infinite values possible for (b,c) for which the above equation holds.